# What was Thor eating in “Avengers: Endgame”?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-endgame

We see Thor laid back in the beginning of *Avengers: Endgame*. He seems to be chewing something. Any clues as to what it was?

[image: Thor leans back in his chair with a bowl of food in front of him]

Comment: What was he eating? Everything!

Comment: Not a salad, according to his mother.

Answer (score 4):

Thor is eating out of a **bowl of bread** in this scene. All one has to do is a quick Google search of "thor eating bread" to find a plethora of results to confirm this. For the sake of this answer, I found a video specifically dedicated to Thor eating bread in this scene: [Eating bread while avengers panic asmr](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0T25zAj4ic) (obviously it's a joke but its use as evidence remains valid)

If one were to stretch a little bit, one could say that it foreshadows his transformation later in the movie, as he is eating his emotions away and  "bread makes you fat."